# How to plot the described figure in mathematica?

Tags: plotting, homework

I have had an assignment for which I was supposed to calculate the maximum volume of the figure. I have done it and found my maximum points in the figure. The assignment does not require to plot the result of the maximum volume of the figure. However I would still like to plot the result. I do know how to plot a cone and a cylinder. However, I do not know how to plot a cone that is on top of a cylinder and a cone upside down under the cylinder.

The figure looks like this:

[image]

I would really appreciate all kind of help.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica S.E. To start: 1) take the [introductory tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), since the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) consider accepting the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking checkmark sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something to get you started

```
ParametricPlot3D[{{Cos[x], Sin[x], 2 y}, {Cos[x] y, Sin[x] y, 
   3 - y}, {Cos[x] y, Sin[x] y, -1 + y}}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 Mesh -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
 PlotStyle -> FaceForm[Opacity[1, Blue]], Boxed -> False, 
 Axes -> False]
```

> [image: fig]

Answer (score 3):

```
shape[r_, h_, H_] := {
  Cone[{{0, 0, H/2}, {0, 0, H/2 + h}}, r],
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, -H/2}, {0, 0, H/2}}, r],
  Cone[{{0, 0, -H/2}, {0, 0, -H/2 - h}}, r]}

Graphics3D[shape[1, 2, 3]]
```

[image]

```
vol = FullSimplify[Sum[Volume[s], {s, shape[r, h, H]}], 
  Assumptions -> h > 0 && H > 0 && r > 0]
(* 1/3 (2 h + 3 H) π r^2 *)

(* -4*(π r ^2) to get rid of the four hidden surfaces:
circles contributed by base+top of cylinder and cones *)
surfarea = 
 FullSimplify[
  Sum[SurfaceArea[s], {s, shape[r, h, H]}] - 4*(π r ^2), 
  Assumptions -> h > 0 && H > 0 && r > 0]
(* 2 π r (H + Sqrt[h^2 + r^2]) *)
```

Comment: thank you. I was thinking, when calculating the values of r, h and H. How would I change the values (r, h and H) so that I can get the maximum volume?

Comment: @Sopie shape[1,2,3] - you can put in anything. The maximum volume is infinite so your question doesn't make sense. The height H, height h, and radius are completely unconstrained. Perhaps some detail must be missing from your question like if there's some relationship given between those parameters.

Comment: The question of the problem is following: Determine dimensions (radius, cone and cylinder height) of the buoy so that the total volume is maximized. What I want to do is to show how the figure looks like after determining the radius, and the hights).

Comment: @Sopie and there's nothing else in the question given? The answer is infinity then. Obviously you could take a shape like this and scale it up to the size of Jupiter and beyond... so for the question to have a non-infinite answer, there must be some other constraint

Comment: No, but he did say that the answer should be expressed in A. A is the area of the buoy. As I said, the question does not require any plotting but I was thinking it would be better to have one.

Answer (score 2):

I’m a professor and sometimes I don’t pose questions well. I suspect this is the case here.  When given an ill-posed question, just say “I believe this question is ill posed. I can make a shape of arbitrarily large volume. But here is an expression for V that has this form: V = (something with out units) A^(3/2)”